# Single variable derivative of expression(symbolic)

Tags: javascript, math, expression-trees, algebra

I have written an HTML code using JavaScript to differentiate a single variable function. 
My code is [here](http://jsbin.com/okipOwE/1/edit?html,output). I have used Mathjax to print the output. But the output produced is not simplified. For example, the derivative of `sin(x)/cos(x)` is produced as

```
((((cos(x))*(cos(x)))-((sin(x))*(-(sin(x)))))/((cos(x))^2))
```

which can be simplified to

```
(sin(x)^2+cos(x)^2)/cos(x)^2
```

I have constructed expression tree with the application of Dijkstra's shunting yard algorithm. And then constructed the expression tree of derivative recursively. But I have problem with the simplification.

Can anyone please help with the simplification of the output produced? My knowledge is not beyond elementary data structures.

Comment: Please be more specific in the question. At least examples what you are getting and what is desirable output. The question should work even if the link is dead.

Comment: I have added an example now. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @SumitKumarJha - What IvanH was asking for is code sample. Do you have a specific coding/algorithmic problem - either with correctness or performance of your code?

Comment: @Chandranshu- I wanted to know, if there exists an algorithm for simplification of algebraic expression.(Like simplification of radicals etc.)

Comment: I think you want at least three things: removal of unneeded parentheses, collection of a^n * a ==> a^(n+1), and collection of sign terms.

Comment: SICP discusses symbolic differentiation and how to achieve a few simplifications by adding rules to the differentiation: http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node39.html

Comment: You could always look into an existing library? https://github.com/jiggzson/nerdamer

Answer (score 1):

Well i can think only of implementation of algebraic rules.

- extremlly hard to code
- even harder to debug

1.create a list of simplification equations

- like:

  ```
  cos^2(x)+sin^2(x)=1
  ...
  ```
- this is easy
- but be careful not to add cyclic equations here (so it would loop without end)
- or rules that not simplify the output

2.create list of substitution methods

3.go through equation

- test all the simplification rules
- if it is applyable then apply it (hard to code)
- if none found then try substitutions (extremlly hard to code it right)
- if still none found then stop

4.do the point 3 for all representations of equation

- equation can be writen in more ways
- multiplicative
- exponentiol
- fractional,etc ...
- you need to test all the variations